How to include "Proxies" information in APS
I am trying to follow Tutorials for making Hubs Browser: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/
I followed the tutorial exactly but it doesn't work.
In my previous experience, the problem usually happened using forge function. For example:
service.authCallbackMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    const internalCredentials = await authenticationClient.getThreeLeggedToken(APS_CLIENT_ID, req.query.code, APS_CALLBACK_URL, {
        clientSecret: APS_CLIENT_SECRET
});

If I use getTHreeLeggedToken function, it doesn't work because of Proxy information.
Our company's secure group doesn't allow without proxy.
Is there any other way?
const { SdkManagerBuilder } = require('@aps_sdk/autodesk-sdkmanager');
const { AuthenticationClient, Scopes, ResponseType } = require('@aps_sdk/authentication');
const { DataManagementClient } = require('@aps_sdk/data-management');
const { APS_CLIENT_ID, APS_CLIENT_SECRET, APS_CALLBACK_URL } = require('../config.js');

const sdkManager = SdkManagerBuilder.create().build();
const authenticationClient = new AuthenticationClient(sdkManager);
const dataManagementClient = new DataManagementClient(sdkManager);
const service = module.exports = {};

service.getAuthorizationUrl = () => authenticationClient.authorize(APS_CLIENT_ID, ResponseType.Code, APS_CALLBACK_URL, [
    Scopes.DataRead,
    Scopes.DataCreate,
    Scopes.ViewablesRead
]);

service.authCallbackMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    const internalCredentials = await authenticationClient.getThreeLeggedToken(APS_CLIENT_ID, req.query.code, APS_CALLBACK_URL, {
        clientSecret: APS_CLIENT_SECRET
    });
    const publicCredentials = await authenticationClient.getRefreshToken(APS_CLIENT_ID, internalCredentials.refresh_token, {
        clientSecret: APS_CLIENT_SECRET,
        scopes: [Scopes.ViewablesRead]
    });
    req.session.public_token = publicCredentials.access_token;
    req.session.internal_token = internalCredentials.access_token;
    req.session.refresh_token = publicCredentials.refresh_token;
    req.session.expires_at = Date.now() + internalCredentials.expires_in * 1000;
    next();
};

service.authRefreshMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { refresh_token, expires_at } = req.session;
    if (!refresh_token) {
        res.status(401).end();
        return;
    }

    if (expires_at < Date.now()) {
        const internalCredentials = await authenticationClient.getRefreshToken(APS_CLIENT_ID, refresh_token, {
            clientSecret: APS_CLIENT_SECRET,
            scopes: [Scopes.DataRead, Scopes.DataCreate]
        });
        const publicCredentials = await authenticationClient.getRefreshToken(APS_CLIENT_ID, internalCredentials.refresh_token, {
            clientSecret: APS_CLIENT_SECRET,
            scopes: [Scopes.ViewablesRead]
        });
        req.session.public_token = publicCredentials.access_token;
        req.session.internal_token = internalCredentials.access_token;
        req.session.refresh_token = publicCredentials.refresh_token;
        req.session.expires_at = Date.now() + internalCredentials.expires_in * 1000;
    }
    req.internalOAuthToken = {
        access_token: req.session.internal_token,
        expires_in: Math.round((req.session.expires_at - Date.now()) / 1000),
    };
    req.publicOAuthToken = {
        access_token: req.session.public_token,
        expires_in: Math.round((req.session.expires_at - Date.now()) / 1000),
    };
    next();
};

service.getUserProfile = async (accessToken) => {
    const resp = await authenticationClient.getUserInfo(accessToken);
    return resp;
};

